# Problemas con While anidado PHP y consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo unas consultas en php con mysql a dos tablas, las cuales anido con while para poder hacer una resta y obtener la diferencia entre un array y el otro, el problema surje en el segundo array al tratar de comparar el primer while con el segundo, se alteran los valores poniendo el mismo valor en todo el array. Aqui mi codigo.

```
<?php 
         $query = "SELECT fecha, TRUNCATE(pml_mda,2) as PML_MDA FROM $tabla where $zona_carga='$zona' and fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin' order by fecha, hora asc;";
         $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
         $query2 = "SELECT fecha, TRUNCATE(pml_mtr,2) as PML_MTR FROM $tabla_mtr where $zona_carga='$zona' and fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin' order by fecha, hora asc;";
         $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2);
         $fechas_origen = array();
         while ($rorigen=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
             $fechas_origen[$rorigen['fecha']] = $rorigen['PML_MDA']; //si imprimo este array lo muestra correcto
            
                 while ($rdestino = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
                 {  
                  $fechas_origen[$rorigen['fecha']] = $rorigen['PML_MDA'];  // al imprimirlo en este lado del while solo trae el primer valor y lo repite a lo largo del array     
                        $rdestino['fecha'];
                         $fechas_origen[$rdestino['fecha']];
                         $rdestino['PML_MTR'];
                         echo number_format(($fechas_origen[$rdestino['fecha']]/$moneda)-(($rdestino['PML_MTR']/$moneda)),2).",";
                }
              }
      ?>
```

El problema es cuando intento hacer la resta entre los dos solo me trae el segundo valor y el primer array lo trae repetido con el primer valor solo se conserva antes del 2do while.

Me podrian orientar que estoy haciendo mal o si necesitan mas elementos con gusto lo subo, gracias.

Los valores de $fecha_ini y $fecha_fin son variables son dos dias distintos ejemplo el dia 25 de enero al 25 de enero , esto genera una consulta que trae todo depende del numero de dias que sean entre cada fecha pueden ser anios de consulta.

Tabla pml_mda_c

```
FECHA          |     HORA     |   PML_MDA  |
2022-01-25  |          1        |          10        |
2022-01-25  |          2        |          12        |
2022-01-25  |          3        |          23        |
....
2022-01-25  |          24       |          23        |
```

Tabla pml_mtr_c

```
FECHA       |        HORA       |       PML_MTR      |
2022-01-25  |          1        |          22        |
2022-01-25  |          2        |          32        |
2022-01-25  |          3        |          34        |
2022-01-25  |          4        |          11        |
2022-01-25  |          5        |          21        |
2022-01-25  |          6        |          64        |
2022-01-25  |          7        |          23        |
....
2022-01-25  |          24      |          12         |
```

Hice una consulta distinta uniendo las dos consultas y restando los campos

```
SELECT a.fecha, a.hora, a.pml_mda,  b.pml_mtr, TRUNCATE((a.pml_mda-b.pml_mtr),2) as dart
FROM pml_mda_cenace a, pml_mtr_cenace b
WHERE a.clv_nodo = b.clv_nodo
and a.fecha between '2022-01-21' and '2022-01-25'
and a.clv_nodo = '02LGP-115' 
group by a.hora;
```

me trae de resultado mal ya que repite el primer valor de pml_mtr en toda la consulta:

```
fecha      hora pml_mda pml_mtr dart
2022-01-25  1   1387.07 948.53  438.54
2022-01-25  2   943.81  948.53  -4.72
2022-01-25  3   880.96  948.53  -67.57
2022-01-25  4   864.51  948.53  -84.02
2022-01-25  5   863.81  948.53  -84.72
2022-01-25  6   877.26  948.53  -71.27
...
2022-01-25  22  2060.65 948.53  1112.12
2022-01-25  23  2158.08 948.53  1209.55
2022-01-25  24  1840.2  948.53  891.67
```

Si hago las consultas aparte el resultado de MTR es el correcto.

```
    fecha  hora pml_mtr
2022-01-25  1   948.53
2022-01-25  2   888.57
2022-01-25  3   846.98
2022-01-25  4   822.64
2022-01-25  5   829.34
2022-01-25  6   835.5
...
2022-01-25  22  1019.34
2022-01-25  23  980.66
2022-01-25  24  919.65
```

El resultado al cual quiero llegar seria

```
fecha     hora  pml_mda pml_mtr dart
2022-01-25  1   1387.07 948.53  438.54
2022-01-25  2   943.81  888.57  55.24
2022-01-25  3   880.96  846.98  33.98
2022-01-25  4   864.51  822.64  41.87
2022-01-25  5   863.81  829.34  34.47
2022-01-25  6   877.26  835.5   41.76
...
2022-01-25  21  2257.29 1043.06 1214.23
2022-01-25  22  2060.65 1019.34 1041.31
2022-01-25  23  2158.08 980.66  1177.42
2022-01-25  24  1840.2  919.65  920.55
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces todo esto en una sola consulta SQL? Estás consultando dos veces a la misma tabla.

Comment: Son dos tablas, una se llama pml_mda_c
la otra es pml_mtr_c traen exactamente los mismos campos solo cambia el nombre y el contenido de la informacion

Comment: Entonces puedes unir ambas tablas mediante un `JOIN` y trabajar con un solo conjunto de resultados, **si es que hay un valor que sea común a ambas tablas** claro está.

Comment: Si @A.Cedano tienen en comun la misma fecha y la misma hora edite mi pregunta mostrando la estructura de las dos tablas, la consulta practicamente me trae n dias que separen la fecha inicial con la fecha final y cada dia con sus 24 hrs.

Comment: He eliminado mi respuesta, @A.Cedano tiene razón, debes unir la consulta y todo será más facil.  La próxima vez que preguntes muestranos todos los datos relevantes, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru gracias por tu apoyo de antemano, he editado mi pregunta original aniadiendo la consulta mysql la cual me manda un errro me repite el valor del campo mtr

Comment: @A.Cedano amigo edite mi pregunta agregue una consulta y no se por que me manda ese error.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices cuando te repite los valores? Por favor, evita poner imágenes de resultados, mejor copia y pega el texto de los resultados en la pregunta como texto y dinos qué es lo que repite exactamente y qué dato esperas.

Comment: Puede que el problema sea que debes agrupar por fecha, no por hora,  algo así: `group by a.fecha` si observas, el valor de hora es diferente.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tus comentarios me ayudan mucho a mejorar en mis preguntas, lo agrupo por hora por que si lo hago por fecha me junta las 24 hrs en una sola linea ya edite mi pregunta ojala este ok

Comment: Prueba a agrupar por hora entonces, pero en ambas tablas, algo así: `group by a.hora, b.hora`  Y gracias por le edición, aunque basta con poner unas pocas filas de cada caso donde se refleje el problema completo, es lo que se llama **Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable**. Si pones demasiadas filas es más complejo analizar de una sola vista todo el contexto.

Comment: cuando lo agrupo asi  `group by a.hora, b.hora` me repite ahora la columna pml_mda

Comment: Y, ¿qué debe ocurrir con esa columna en el resultado final? ¿Podrías por favor [crear un fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) donde incluyas **un pequeño set de datos (4 o 5 filas)** de tus dos tablas, para verificar. Así a la brava es complicado ver lo que ocurre.

Comment: cada columna debe traer sus 24 valores pero en la consulta me repite el primer valor a lo largo de la consulta de mysql en el caso de `b.pml_mtr` pero `a.pml_mda` lo trae correcto, lo subi en la pregunta editada

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133726/discussion-between-joaquin-duran-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la última edición, puedes unir las tablas con [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) para obtener los valores adecuados:

```
SELECT a.fecha, a.hora, a.pml_mda,
    b.pml_mtr, TRUNCATE((a.pml_mda-b.pml_mtr),2) as dart
FROM pml_mda_cenace a
LEFT JOIN pml_mtr_cenace b
    ON a.fecha = b.fecha AND a.hora = b.hora
WHERE a.clv_nodo = b.clv_nodo
    AND a.fecha BETWEEN '2022-01-21' AND '2022-01-25'
    AND a.clv_nodo = '02LGP-115' 
GROUP BY a.fecha, a.hora
ORDER BY a.fecha, a.hora
```

El `LEFT JOIN` es para asignar valores nulos a los campos de la segunda tabla en caso de no haber coincidencia y el criterio son las columnas fecha y hora.

Se sugiere usar todos los campos que se deben agrupar para evitar problemas, porque en algunos servidores pueden tener configuraciones diferentes, provocando errores por la directiva [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: El que sabe sabe dejame borrar mi otra pregunta gracias